# Cutting certain string of variable

Tags: string, bash

I'd like to cut off some special strings of a variable.
The variable contains the following, including a lot of blank space before <div...  and a class attribute:

```
           <div data-href="/www.somewebspace.com" class="class1 class2">
```

I would like to extract the contents of the `data-href` attribute i.e have this output `/www.somewebspace.com`

I tried out the following code, the output starts with the contents of the `data-href` attribute and the class attribute.

```
echo $Test | grep -oP '(?<=<div data-href=").*(?=")'
```

How can I get rid of the class attribute?

Kind regards and grateful for every reply,
X3nion

P.S. Some other question arouse. I've got this strings I'd like to extract from a text file:

```
                <div class="aditem-addon">
                   Today, 23:23</div>`
```

What would be the correct command to extract only the "Today, 23:23" without any spaces and spaces before and after the term?
Maybe I would have to delete the black spaces before?

Comment: try a non greedy quantifier ie `*?`

Comment: While this one is probably solvable, but obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @X3nion if any of the answers solve your problem mark them as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

your regex is correct, you only need to adjust the greediness of the `*` quantifier:

- `*` is a greedy quantifier : match as much as possible whilst getting a match
- `*?` is a reluctant quantifier : match the minimum characters to get a match

```
# Correct
Test='<div data-href="/www.somewebspace.com" class="fdgks"></div>'
echo $Test | grep -oP '(?<=<div data-href=").*?(?=")'
#> /www.somewebspace.com
# the desired output

# WRONG
echo $Test | grep -oP '(?<=<div data-href=").*(?=")'
#> /www.somewebspace.com" class="fdgks
# didn't stop until it matched the last quote `"`
echo $Test$Test | grep -oP '(?<=<div data-href=").*(?=")'
#> /www.somewebspace.com" class="fdgks"></div><div data-href="/www.somewebspace.com" class="fdgks
# same as the last one
```

for a more detailed explanation about the difference between greedy, reluctant and possessive quantifiers ([see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html#difs))

---

## EDIT

```
echo $Test$Test | grep -Poz '(?<=<div class="aditem-addon">\n ).*?(?=<\/div>)'
#> Today, 23:23
#> Today, 23:23
```

- `\n`  matches a newline an a leading space.

if the string you're looking for contains the newline character `\n` you'll need to add the `z` option to grep i.e the call will be `grep -ozP`

Comment: Hey Abdessabour Mtk, Thanks for your reply! That worked out very well. How did you see the missing adjustment regarding the greediness?

Comment: if you don't tell the regex engine to be non greedy it will gobble up as much characters i.e it won't stop until the last `"`. for example if your div had another attribute after the class `grep` will return it too.

Comment: @X3nion I added an explanation and some references

Comment: @ Abdessabour Mtk  Thanks for your detailed reply! I added something as P.S. in my message. Could you maybe answer to it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works well with -oP although the Today is in a new line. Shall I better use -ozP to be on the safe side? And there is one single whitespace in front of Today. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: @X3nion check the new answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless the input is very simple, considering using xmllint or other html parsing tool. For the very simple cases, you can use bash solution:

```
#! /bin/sh
s='           <div data-href="/www.somewebspace.com" class="class1 class2"> '

s1=${s##*data-href=\"}
s1=${s1%%\"*}
echo "$s1"
```

Which will print

```
/www.somewebspace.com
```